# WordPress how to add another page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the newest version of WordPress (version 2.8.4)

I'm wondering how I would add an additional page.
I have a navigation that looks something like this.

`home | about us | contact us | ... etc.`

I read somewhere to go to `pages -> add new` but it forces me to put the content within WordPress rather than edit a PHP file itself.

How would I be able to enter PHP in it? Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to add home, "About us" pages:

1. You have to create template pages for this.
2. For this you need 3 files: `header.php, index.php and footer.php`.
3. If you are using an existing theme, you will find these three files in your theme folder itself.
4. For creating your home page, copy the following into your index.php file:

   ```
   <?php get_header(); ?>
   <body>
     /* include whatever u want in ur body tag */
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
   ```
5. `index.php` will be automatically assigned to home page.
6. For the "about us" page, create a file named `aboutus.php` (whatever name you want with .php 
     extension) and copy and paste this code.

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Template Name: aboutus //don't forget to add this name according to ur page name
    *
    * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
    */
   ?>
   <?php get_header(); ?>
   <body>
   /* whatever u want in ur body tag */
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
   ```
7. Then go to dashboard of your website or blog, there click `pages->Add new`,
     give the Title as Home. Then click publish button on right side of the (Add new page) window.
8. Then, on left side of the screen, again click `pages->add new`, then enter title as "about us"
     and then, in right side of this window, you will see a dropdown box named template, click the dropdown and select "about us" from it. Then click publish button.
9. Now we are going to create menus to appear in the website or blog. For this,

   1. On left side of window,click `Appearence->Menus`.
   2. On left side down of window you will see Pages heading, in that click Most
        Recent, check home, aboutus pages and click Add to Menu button.
   3. Then, the selected pages are displayed on right side and click Save Menu button on right corner.
   4. Then, on left top corner, click your website or blog name to view your website with the two menus with their pages.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a [Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates)** in your theme folder, then set the page to use that.

If you want to do it without creating a Template, you may be able to use a plugin such as [Exec-PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/), however **this brings with it a bunch of possible security issues**.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a content page outside of Wordpress and outside of the WP loop? You still need to use a template and WP includes or you'll run into permalink problems.

You can make a WP page but exclude it from navigation, if that's what you're after, with something like [Exclude Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you're asking, but if what you're looking for is a way to have a link in your WordPress navigation that goes to a page you create outside of WordPress, you can use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/

If this and the other answers aren't any help, you might want to edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do with the php.

Good luck!